# How to write parquet file to ECS in Flask python using boto or boto3

Tags: python, flask, boto, parquet, amazon-ecs

I have flask python rest api which is called by another flask rest api.
the input for my api is one parquet file (FileStorage object) and ECS connection and bucket details.
I want to save parquet file to ECS in a specific folder using boto or boto3
the code I have tried

```
  def uploadFileToGivenBucket(self,inputData,file):
        BucketName = inputData.ecsbucketname
        calling_format = OrdinaryCallingFormat()
        client = S3Connection(inputData.access_key_id, inputData.secret_key, port=inputData.ecsport,
                          host=inputData.ecsEndpoint, debug=2,
                          calling_format=calling_format)
        #client.upload_file(BucketName, inputData.filename, inputData.folderpath)

        bucket = client.get_bucket(BucketName,validate=False)

        key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, inputData.filename)
        fileName = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix=".parquet")
        file.save(fileName)
        with open(fileName.name) as f:
            key.send_file(f)
```

but it is not working and giving me error like...

```
    signature_host = '%s:%d' % (self.host, port)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

I tried google but no luck Can anyone help me with this or any sample code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hit and tried and time, I finally got the solution. I posting it for everyone else who are facing the same issue.

You need to use Boto3 and here is the code...

```
def uploadFileToGivenBucket(self,inputData,file):
    BucketName = inputData.ecsbucketname
    #bucket = client.get_bucket(BucketName,validate=False)
    f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix=".parquet")
    file.save(f)

    endpointurl = "<your endpoints>"
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url=endpointurl, aws_access_key_id=inputData.access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=inputData.secret_key)

    try:
        newkey = 'yourfolderpath/anotherfolder'+inputData.filename
        response = s3_client.upload_file(f.name, BucketName,newkey)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```